# Perl File Reading and RegEx Matching

Tags: regex, perl, file-handling

I'm doing a little perl script, but i've some problem while reading file, and than iterate over regex.

In particulary the file is over multiple line, and for each line, i need to extract some value, i post an example to understand better.

This is sample line of file

```
            1A    OCC OCC  4B  5B  6B  7B  8B    9A
      OCC OCC    12B 13B 14B OCC 16B 17B 18B   OCC OCC
```

i need to match for the first, second, n..,  line separetly:
1A
4B
5B
6B
7B
...

excecpt OCC.

i wrote this code:

```
my $path="file.txt";

open (my $fh, "<", $path);

 while(my $line = <$fh>)
 {
    for ($line =~/(\d{1,2}[A|B|C])/){   
      print " $1";  
 }
}
```

The result that i obtained is only match for the first occurance matched on the line.
1A 12B

How can i extend  for read all line and match the content correctly?

The print result is only for my debugging test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The match as you wrote it captures *once* and it stops. So the `for` loop is over that one number that is inside `(line =~ ...)`.

You can instead use the `/g` *modifier* which will make regex to keep going and find all matches. If you assign that to an array then the operator is in the *list context* and it returns all matches

```
my @matches = $line =~ /\d{1,2}[A-C]/g;
```

Here you don't need the capturing parenthesis since you take the whole match. When in doubt add them. If you simply need any numbers followed by any letters you can use `/\d+\w+/g` instead.

I'd like to make a few more comments.

- Please *always* start your programs with `use warnings;` and `use strict;`
- Always, *always* check calls like `open`

Altogether

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

my $path="file.txt";

open my $fh, "<", $path  or die "Can't open $path: $!";

while (my $line = <$fh>)
{
    my @matches = $line =~ /(\d{1,2}[A-C])/g;

    say "@matches";
}

close $fh;
```

Answer (score 2):

To match all occurrences of a regex, you need to use the `/g` modifier.

Also, as the argument to `for` is evaluated in list context, it would return all the matches at once, so using `$1` would return the same value (the last one) for each match; but you can use the loop variable instead:

```
for ($line =~ /(\d{1,2}[ABC])/g) {
    print " $_";
}
```

But, it's common to loop over the matches with `while` instead, as it returns the matching parts one by one, without the need to have a long list of matches. Here, you need `$1`, as the loop condition is evaluated in scalar context:

```
while ($line =~ /(\d{1,2}[ABC])/g) {
    print " $1";
}
```

Notes: Your input doesn't contain `|`, so I removed it from the character class.